# ADC LPC1768 simple

Tags: arm, keil, adc

this is my code

```
#include "LPC17xx.h"                    // Device header
#include "GPIO_LPC17xx.h"               // Keil::Device:GPIO
uint32_t voltag1 = 0 ;
uint32_t voltag2 = 0 ;
volatile uint32_t adstat;
int blink=1;
int main()
{
    //Config timer
    LPC_TIM1->MCR=2;                         
    LPC_TIM1->MR0=20000000;                 //Match Resgister
    LPC_TIM1->TCR=1; 
    LPC_TIM1->EMR = 0x00000030 ;

    //Config ADC
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 |= (1 << 14) | (1 << 16);    // connect pin to ADC
    LPC_SC->PCONP |= ((1 << 12));                    //enable power of ADC  
    LPC_ADC->ADCR    =  0x06202001;                  //initialaze ADC
    LPC_ADC->ADINTEN =  0x00000100;                  // global interup      
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
    GPIO_SetDir(3,25,GPIO_DIR_OUTPUT);   
    while(1) {}
}

void ADC_IRQHandler(void) 
{
    adstat = LPC_ADC->ADSTAT;       /* Read ADC clears interrupt  */    
    blink++;
    GPIO_PinWrite(3,25,blink%2);
    voltag1 = (LPC_ADC->ADGDR >> 4) & 0xFFF; 
    //voltag2 = (LPC_ADC->ADDR1 >> 4) & 0xFFF; 
}
```

when i use LPC_ADC->ADGDR it work fine but when i use LPC_ADC->ADDR1 its not working , why? 
i used MAT for ADC interup
and when i use LPC_ADC->ADGDR everything works fine
but when i use LPC_ADC->ADDR1 for reading its not working and not change with MAT edge

Answer (score 0):

There are *way too many* magic numbers in your code. Please use the corresponding defines for all those bits. This code is unreadable as is.

There is a wrong comment in your code, the interrupt flag for `ADGDR` is **not** cleared on `ADSTAT` read. Only a read of `ADGDR` clears it, and thats why your code does not work with `ADDR1`.

Had you used the definition to set ADINTEN, you might have spotted your error sooner. That flag is named **ADGDINTEN** and corresponds to the flag in ADGDR only.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable IRQ of ch1 by:

```
LPC_ADC->ADINTEN =  1 << 1;  //0x0002
```